# Extracting the pixels value inside the circle drawn over the raster file using Python

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, geometry, rasterio

I have a GeoTIFF file and a series of the center point. I want to create/draw the circle over the GeoTIFF using these center points and extract the pixels value inside those circles. I want to do it in Python but I don't have any clue how to do that in Python as I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasterio is one of the best possible solutions for extracting raster values for given x, y coordinates.

```
import rasterio

def interpz(vlist, dtmfile):
    with rasterio.open(dtmfile) as src:
        vals = list(src.sample(vlist))
    return [(y[0], y[1],vals[x][0]) for x,y in enumerate(vlist)]

dtm = "path/to/dtm"
points = [(27.996317832013315, 41.84787239262598),
 (27.986272512814367, 41.84761397977615),
 (27.97616636707383, 41.84748698416698),
 (27.96621844967393, 41.84773269557604),
 (27.956179180888633, 41.84819829817567),
 (27.946003866252244, 41.84862714096131)]

points_with_values = interpz(dtm, points)
```

If you want to get stats of pixel values in buffered circles from centers like mean, count, unique, etc I advise using rasterstats.

But all pixel values are required you can use above code after extracting x,y values from circles.

```
from shapely.geometry.point import Point

circles = [ Point(pt).buffer(0.01)  for pt in points]
```

then get all x,y values from circles to send them to `interpz`.